# How can I step into Qt's source code when debugging under Mac OS with Qt-creator

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

I download the qt framework and debugging helper, I can debug my source with Qt creator, but I can't step in to the Qt source code, I have download the source of Qt, how to config the source to let me can trace into the source? or, Must I compile the library from source to do this?

I can trace into Qt source Under Windows using Visual c++, but On Mac, with Qt creator can't.

Comment: Debugger Helpers Do Not Work In 2.0 In OSX 10.6
Created: 06/Aug/10 09:25 PM   Updated: 30/Aug/10 09:06 AM
Affects Version/s:  Qt Creator 2.0.0
Fix Version/s:  None  <-- So ,Maybe it's a bug, who have solved this issue help me please, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary downloads of Qt for Mac do not include any debugging info. The "debug" version of the downloads do. But Nokia forgot to include the source files so it doesn't help you either. Here's a bug reported on this issue: http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-8433

The only way to step into (most) Qt source files on Mac is to download the source files package and build it yourself. Even that doesn't work out of the box (if you can call it that). The installed directory is missing the '`src`' sub-directory which is where all Qt source files need to go. The solution is to create a symbolic link to the '`src`' directory in your build directory.

Even that doesn't work 100% of the time. I still run into Qt functions that I can't step into. But that's rare after all the mocking.